# formatting strings with StringBuilder.AppendFormat isn't working as expected

Tags: c#, string, format

I'm trying to create a table with data using StringBuilders AppendFormat method. I want the text in the second and third column to be left aligned.

Here is an example I found on google:
http://www.csharp-examples.net/align-string-with-spaces/

However, using the same code as the website I get different results. The placement of the second column text depends on the length of the first column text. Am I doing this wrong? Is there a better method that would be more suited for this task? I want a certain amount of space from the first character of the first column to the first character of the second column ( like the setw() method in c++)

```
symbolTableToString.AppendFormat(" {0,-20}  {1,-10}  {2,-10} {3,-10}",dataNode.token, dataNode.tokenClass, dataNode.tokenMode, dataNode.alias).AppendLine();
```

I'm putting each line into a text box and am unable to use a different widget as this is part of a homework assignment. [image]

Comment: try setting the text box to have a fixed width font like Courier.

Comment: @hatchet Thats it! thank you! Post it as an answer so I can accept the answer :)

Comment: You should use a DataGridView.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your textbox has a variable width font, so using counts of spaces to align columns will almost never turn out well. Change the Font property of the textbox to a fixed width font such as Courier New.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem isn't the AppendFormat, that actually seems to work correctly. Set that text box to use a monospaced font, e.g. Courier New or Consolas.